# Take week dates from Sunday to Saturday and get month value

Tags: vba, excel

I am having the below code to get month value. So I can get month value, even if the week is present in two months.

```
week = 1
year_to_use = 2018
month_at_start_of_week = Month(DateAdd("ww", week - 1, DateSerial(year_to_use, 1, 1)))
month_at_end_of_week = Month(DateAdd("ww", week, DateSerial(year_to_use, 1, 1) - 1))
```

My previous code gets the week dates from Monday to Sunday, but I want to consider the week dates start/end from Sunday to Saturday

[image]

Also I need to get count of days in both `month_at_start_of_week` and `month_at_end_of_week`

Answer (score 0):

If instead of using the DateSerial which actually refers to the 1st of January 2018, which is a Monday, you were to use a date which is a known Sunday, then your code would work as expected, such as below:

```
Sub foo()
    week = 5
    year_to_use = 2018
    month_at_start_of_week = Month(DateAdd("ww", week - 1, "30/12/2017"))
    month_at_end_of_week = Month(DateAdd("ww", week, "30/12/2017"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your Code.
But it gives the same output what my code gives
For testing week 13, start and end month should be 3, buts its not(3,4)

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi, please try using the date 30/12/2017, I believe that should work as expected as I was supposed to minus a day from the result. Let me know if any further issues.

Comment: Great. You are correct, If I change the date to 30/12/2017 its work;
But again how can I use it for dynamic year

Comment: Sorry @ManiMuthuPandi I'm not sure what you mean by "Dynamic Year", please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped? :) Thanks.

Comment: Here you have hard-coded the initial date, how about if the year is 2019 or 2020..

Comment: Sure, you helped a lot

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi You would have to find the last Saturday of the year and use that date to make this dynamic. There are lots of ways to achieve that, for example: [Check this link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/761996-determine-the-date-of-the-last-sunday-in-a-month.html)